# Understanding FB Page IDs from API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm working with the the fb page and I have pulled posts from a use using:

```
$fbapp = PVConfiguration::getConfiguration('afbapp');

        $facebook = new Facebook( array('appId' => $fbapp -> app_id, 'secret' => $fbapp -> app_secret, 'cookie' => true  ));

$facebook->api( $this -> fb_page_id . '/feed');
```

Now a sample result looks something like this:

```
[0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 311007125672751_315405295232910
                    [from] => Array
                        (
                            [category] => Retail and consumer merchandise
                            [name] => Example Demos
                            [id] => 311007125672751
                        )

                    [story] => Phonefare Demos added a new photo.
                    [story_tags] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 311007125672751
                                            [name] => Example Demos
                                            [offset] => 0
                                            [length] => 15
                                            [type] => page
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [picture] => https://fbcdn-photos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash2/576447_315405255232904_1958203550_s.jpg
                    [link] => https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=315405255232904&set=a.315405251899571.62826.311007125672717&type=1&relevant_count=1
                    [icon] => https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yz/r/StEh3RhPvjk.gif
                    [actions] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => Comment
                                    [link] => https://www.facebook.com/311007125672751/posts/315405295232910
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => Like
                                    [link] => https://www.facebook.com/311007125672751/posts/315405295232910
                                )

                        )

                    [privacy] => Array
                        (
                            [description] => Public
                            [value] => EVERYONE
                            [friends] => 
                            [networks] => 
                            [allow] => 
                            [deny] => 
                        )

                    [type] => photo
                    [status_type] => added_photos
                    [object_id] => 315405255232904
                    [created_time] => 2012-12-21T15:04:37+0000
                    [updated_time] => 2012-12-21T15:04:37+0000
                    [shares] => Array
                        (
                            [count] => 2
                        )

                    [likes] => Array
                        (
                            [data] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 45608554
                                            [name] => Michele A
                                        )

                                )

                            [paging] => Array
                                (
                                    [cursors] => Array
                                        (
                                            [after] => NDU2MDg1NjY=
                                            [before] => NDU2MDg1NjY=
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )
```

My greatest point of confusion is this. I want to store the post in the database as a bigint. But the return id is

> 311007125672751_315405295232910

, and I'm guessing its two IDS. So which ID should I be storing in the database to reference later? What are both IDs for? Is there a fundamental flaw for breaking the IDS apart to start them as BigInts/UUIDs?

Comment: Not much “guessing” needed to figure out that the first part is the page id. And you should not store those ids as integers, use strings instead.

Comment: @CBroe why string? What I am really asking is what is the disadvantage of storing breaking that id and storing it as a bigint/uuid/